# File upload and saving it into directory

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I am using Spring Framework's MultipartFile to allow a user to upload a pdf file, and I want to store the file in a directory:

For this I use the method tranferTo () but it still doesn't work!!

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
    public CV handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {

     File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename());
         System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
           file.transferTo(convFile );
}
```

How can I add the destination path?

Answer (score 2):

Store in Catalina which is parent folder to your project folder

```
   String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
          File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "yourfolderName");
          if (!dir.exists())
              dir.mkdirs();

          // Create the file on server
          java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
          String Path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + (new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString().replace(":", "").toString().replace(".", ".").toString().replace(" ","").toString().replace("-","").toString()+".pdf";
```

Or Store in specific folder in your project such as folder

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/uploadFile", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(ModelMap model,@RequestParam(value="file", required = false) MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request){

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        //filter for checking file extewnsion
        if(file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpg") || file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
            //if file is >2 MB or < 2MB
            double size = file.getSize();
            double kilobytes = (size / 1024);
            double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
            if(megabytes<2){
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String filePath = request.getRealPath("/")+"yourFolderName\\ProfileImages\\"+SessionManagement.getUserName()+".jpg";
            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            //console call
        }
        else{
            model.put("error", "Please select File less than 2 MB");
            return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
        }
        }else{
            model.put("error", "Please select JPEG File");
            return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
        }
    } else {
        model.put("error", "Please select File");
        return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
    }
}
```